# Nested Dropdown Menu of Bootstrap

Tags: routes, navigation

I would like to add Nested bootstrap menu in my project. (I'm using the Bootstrap Business Theme.)
I already tried with the [Superfish](https://www.drupal.org/project/superfish) module.. But I don't like that much because the appearance of menu is not good looking and have to overwrite many CSS files.
I also tested with TB Mega Menu. It doesn't work. I put TBMenu Block in Navigation block. But the whole menu was totally disappear. I don't know why it happen like that.

Anyone knows other flexible dropdown menu for bootstrap theme?

Answer (score 1):

Responsive Menus module is suitable for bootstrap theme. 
https://www.drupal.org/project/responsive_menus

Comment: That module can be used for DropDown Menu ? I want to do is Dropdown with submenu in normal view. It does not appear not even in normal view.

Comment: Give it some time man. Configurations are bit tricky.